# How do you combine cases and sub equations?

Tags: cases, subequations

My code is:

```
\begin{numcases}{ P(X_1=x_1,...,X_K=x_)=}
   \frac{N!}{x_1!...x_k!}p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}...p_k^{x_k},& \text{when} \sum_{i=1}^kx_i=N 
    \label{multinomial}
    \\
    0 & \text{otherwise,} \label{negative}
\end{numcases}
```

which results in

[image]

Is there any way of having equations 3.6a and 3.6b instead of 3.6 and 3.7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `subnumcases`: ([See `texdoc cases` for full documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cases/cases.pdf))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\begin{document}
\begin{subnumcases}{ P(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_K=x_K)=\label{eq}}
   \frac{N!}{x_1!\dotsm x_k!}p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}\dotsm p_k^{x_k},& when $\sum_{i=1}^kx_i=N$ \label{multinomial}\\
    0 & otherwise, \label{negative}
\end{subnumcases}
\eqref{multinomial} and \eqref{negative} are part of \eqref{eq}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Do please replace the first instance of `...` with `\dots` and the second and third instances with `\dotsb` (or `\cdots`).

Comment: @Mico Thank you. Done (With `\dotsm` instead of `\dotsb`)

Comment: @MarcelKrüger how do you reference this equation?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `subnumcases` environment. Note that the part after `&` is in text mode, so any formula requires a pair`$ ... $`.  I also added some improvements: : medsize commands from `nccmath` for the fractional coefficient and the sum symbol, and smashing the upperpart of the latter for a better symmetry of the brace:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{cases} 

\begin{document}

\begin{subnumcases}{ P(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_K=x_k)=}
   \mfrac{N!}{x_1!\dots x_k!}\,p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}\dots p_k^{x_k},& when $ \smash[t]{\medop\sum\limits_{i=1}^k}x_i=N $
    \label{multinomial}
    \\
    0 & otherwise, \label{negative}
\end{subnumcases}

\end{document}
```

[image]